# Preferred method for renaming endpoint and handling deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP MVC Web API project that works perfectly fine when running through localhost, using the default api/ routing and nomenclature.

It's time to install on its destination server, and now I have been provided with a rather lengthy preferred endpoint name.

I am having difficulties getting this to work properly.  I want my endpoint to operate as http://example.com/funkypath/ourapp/v1 for a default Get() call.  It's implemented on http://example.com/api

```html
[Route("funkypath/ourapp/v1")]
public IEnumerable<MyServiceRequest> Get()
{
...
}
```

How do I get from here to there?  I'm getting Resource not located messages using this example.

Also.... should I recreate this as a physical path to the deployed web api, or should I use an alias on the website and install the web api wherever I want under the docroot?  e.g. install on X:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapi, set up an alias for funkypath/ourapp/v1 that points to that document root.

Help!  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should be able to setup any route you want right within your project without any physical path stuff.

This might help: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)

Comment: So I understand partially how to do that, but my question is really more in line with "what is the preferred method"?  Should I put the web service code physically in the same path structure on the web server?  or should i put it somewhere else and redirect doing attribute routing?

Comment: A little confused. So there is another app at "funkypath" or "ourapp"? My suggestion is physically put all your apps on the server like this: X:\path\AppRoot, X:\path\App1, X:\path\App2, etc. In IIS map the site to AppRoot, and map each app to its path - try not to nest the apps in the file system. You can nest the apps in IIS, but remember that Web.config values get inherited, can get ugly. Your best bet is not to share a path with another app in IIS, put yours at "funkypath" and use routing to get the desired path. Use your local IIS to experiment. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Trey!  that's what i was looking for, appreciate it!